# Concatenate Constant String and Enum

Tags: c#, string, enums, constants

I have a large C# class which is full of nothing but `public const string` fields. However, in one case I am trying to concatenate a string and a enum value into a `const string` field, like this:

```
public const string GET_VALUES = "SELECT * FROM [tbl] WHERE [id] = " + Enum.Val;
```

However, I get this compiler error:

```
'Namespace.SqlStatements.GET_VALUES' must be constant
```

I know I could drop the `const` clause, but I would like to keep all fields within this class consistent. Is it possible to concatenate a constant string and a enum in C#?

Comment: You can use `public readonly`... You cannot use `const` because a const string has to be known at compile time. String concatenation with an enum value requires the string transformation of that enum value -- something that happens during run-time and not during compilation of the program.

Comment: @elgonzo Good idea, but that doesn't quite fit the consistency I had mentioned I was trying to keep. If there isn't any other way, then `readonly` would be the way to go.

Comment: I expanded my first comment. See there why you can't use `const` in this case...

Comment: BTW, do be careful when manipulating SQL statements in code and make sure you aren't opening yourself up to a Sql Injection attack!

Comment: @PhilipPittle I'm very picky about these kinds of things, too. Since the enum is strictly programmer-defined, I was ok with not using a prepared statement.

Comment: @SujithKarivelil How did I miss that?? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From MSDN:

> A constant expression is an expression that can be fully evaluated at compile time. Therefore, the only possible values for constants of reference types are string and a null reference.

In your case, the enum will have to be converted to a string using `ToString`, which is not possible at compile time. I'd suggest you change it to `readonly` as elgonzo mentioned.

Comment: However, I'm not calling `ToString()` on the enum, I'm looking for its integer value. So the enum value can't be resolved at compile time?

Comment: Well no, that's implicitly done by the compiler.